# Method must return int

Tags: java, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I am writing a program that uses Euclids algorithm of GCD(a, b) = GCD(b, r) r = a%b. I wrote a method that should return an integer for the main method to spit out, yet when I call for it to do this it says that it is not returning an integer. Here is the code

```
public class Euclid {

    public static int GCD(int a, int b)
    {
        while (b != 0)
        {
            int r = a%b;
            System.out.println("(" +a+ "," +b+ ")");
            b = r;
            a = b;
            if(b == 0)
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(GCD(36, 20));    
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong.  b=r;a=b results in a=r as well. You probably meant a=b;b=r.

Comment: Thank you I just realized that after I posted it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code if `b == 0` it will not return an `int` or any value for that matter.  You must handle this condition, most likely by specifying a default return value.

```
  public static int GCD(int a, int b)
    {
        while (b != 0)
        {
            int r = a%b;
            System.out.println("(" +a+ "," +b+ ")");
            b = r;
            a = b;
            if(b == 0)
            {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The compiler can't tell that your method will eventually reach the `b == 0` condition and return. You can refactor it to:

```
    int ret = 1;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int r = a%b;
        System.out.println("(" +a+ "," +b+ ")");
        b = r;
        a = b;
        if(b == 0)
        {
            ret = a;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Comment: True. I didn't really read the algorithm. Just thought: 0 is a strange value for a GCD.

Comment: @JBNizet `gcd(0,0)` is 0. Luchian, you should initialize `ret = a;`, or you'll get wrong results for `gcd(a,0)` with `a > 1`.

Comment: I'm not a math expert, but I've always been told that dividing by 0 didn't make any sense, whatever the numerator is. Computing the GCD of 0 and 0 doesn't make any sense, and should throw an IllegalArgumentException. I agree that ret should be a, though.

Comment: @JBNizet Just came across this again. See [the proposal to remove the `gcd 0 0` error in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-May/016411.html) for a short (very short) outline.