# Why Won't This Return Method Compile?

Tags: java, return

I am trying to make a simple program where you can move one space in four directions by typing in commands. Here is my code:

```
public class Map {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mover {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map map = new Map();

    public int move(int x, int y){
        map.x = x;
        map.y = y;
        String direction = input.next();

        System.out.println("Where will you move?");

        if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("move right")){
            x++;
            return x;
        }

        if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("move left")){
            x--;
            return x;
        }

        if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("move up")){
            y++;
            return y;
        }

        if(direction.equalsIgnoreCase("move down")){
            y--;
            return y;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Mover mover = new Mover();
    }
}
```

The compiler says the problem is that I need to return an int value, but clearly I have in within every if statement I've made. Specifically, it says returning a 'y' value at the very end of the method will solve the problem. After trying this, the errors go away. But when compiled, the program instantly terminates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To address the real issue, "the program instantly terminates", you should probably invoke the method you want to, in your main method: `mover.move(someX, someY);`

Comment: I added a return 0 at the end and invoked the move method in the main class. The program ran, but not as intended. It still print "Where will you move?" until after I've typed the answer.

Comment: Make your call to `input.next()` after printing "Where will you move" since calls to Scanner's input method delay execution until receiving input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method must return int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191611/method-must-return-int)

Answer (score 1):

All the `return` statements are in the condition blocks. Add a return statement to the end (For the case when `direction` does not match anything).

`return 0` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If all your conditions are false, execution of your method will reach the end of your method without hitting a `return` statement. You must provide a return value for that situation.

Add a final line to hone body of your method:

```
return 0; // for example
```

Java methods do not have "default" return values.

Answer (score 0):

Because if all of your if cases fail, you don't have a return value.

You should either return some error-code integer, have a default direction, or throw some sort of exception/error.

```
public int move(int x, int y) throws InvalidDirectionException
{
     ...

     // if all if cases fail:
     throw new InvalidDirectionException("Invalid direction inputted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of your if statements evaluate to true then you won't end up returning anything. Add an else to the end to return an int in case none of the ifs are true

Answer (score 0):

The `move` method has to return a value always. In your code, you need to update the code to written some int value **when none of your if conditions are satisfied**.