# how do you return a value in java function

Tags: java

I really need help with this java class:

My class is as follows:

```
public class Date {

    // fields

    private int month;

    private int day;

    private int year;

    // constructor

    public Date(int month, int day, int year){

        this.month = month;

        this.day = day;

        this.year = year;

    }

    public void setMonth(int month){

        this.month = month;

    }


    public void setDay(int day){

        this.day = day;

    }


    public void setYear(int year){

        this.year = year;

    }

    public int getMonth(){

        return month;

    }

    public int getDay(){

        return day;

    }

    public int getYear(){

        return year;

    }

    public String displayDate(){

        return month + "/" + day + "/" + "/" + year;

    }

public int add( int n)
    {
        if (n <= 20)
            {
                if (month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month==12)
                    { 
                        if ((day+n > 0) && (day+n <=31))
                            day= day+n;
                        else
                            month +=1;
                        if(month>12)
                            year+=1;
                      }
            if (month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11)
                {
                    if ((day+n >0) && (day+n <=30))
                        day= day+n;
                    else
                        month+= 1;
                    if (month>12)
                        year+=1;
                }
            }               
    }
}
```

When I run this I get an error missing return statement on the add method? This method is supposed to add some days (n) to the day, month and year. Any ideas how I would fix this?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754593/why-wont-this-return-method-compile

Comment: how about returning something? there isnt a return in that method

Comment: It's impossible to overstate how bad this class is.  The fact that you've overloaded the java.lang.Date class name will be confusing to everyone that uses your code.  And your implementation is awful.

Comment: @dufymo, I know that there are aleady java libraries that do this. I am not supposed to use any existing implementation in java. Need to create this from scratch. I am really sorry for the bad code, just getting used to java.

Comment: duffymo is suggesting that you use a different name for your custom class rather than `Date`. Perhaps `MyDate` or something so that it doesn't clash with the standard `Date` class.

Answer (score 4):

```
public int add(int n)
```

If it doesn't return anything, then its return type should be `void`:

```
public void add(int n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to return type to void.

Edit:

Or if you want to return a Date object:

```
public Date add( int n)
{
    Date d = new Date();
    d.month = this.month;
    d.year = this.year;
    d.day = this.day;

    if (n <= 20)
        {
            if (d.month==1 || d.month==3 || d.month==5 || d.month==7 || d.month==8 || d.month==10 || d.month==12)
                { 
                    if ((d.day+n > 0) && (d.day+n <=31))
                        d.day= d.day+n;
                    else
                        d.month +=1;
                    if(d.month>12)
                        d.year+=1;
                  }
        if (d.month==4 || d.month==6 || d.month==9 || d.month==11)
            {
                if ((d.day+n >0) && (d.day+n <=30))
                    d.day= d.day+n;
                else
                    d.month+= 1;
                if (d.month>12)
                    d.year+=1;
            }
        }  
    return d;             
}
```

OR use the java Calendar classes, which will do this all for you.

Comment: It cannot be void, I need to return the final date after I add the number of days. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case, the return type should be your own Date class.  Construct a new instance in your add() method.  Copy the month, day, and year fields of 'this' object into your new object.  Then do the addition logic, modifying the new object, and return the new object.